# Could somebody help me normalize a function block?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, numbers, new-operator

Recently I've got to write a code that allows to log a human readable number to console (e.g. seventy four, one hundred twelve...)

I should admit that everything worked out fine, but it's told that I need to remove unnecessary invisible spaces when nothing comes after tens, such as forty or seventy, or hundreds. Should return "two hundred" instead of "two hundred "

I know it's rather stupid cause it doesn't affect the way the input amount looks like but they say that I should fix it anyway. I count on your help so much and let me write down the code here :

```
function helpReadable (number) {
  let num = parseInt(number);
  let out = "";
  switch (parseInt(num / 100)%10) {
    case 0 : break; 
    case 1 : out += "one hundred ";
    break;
    case 2 : out += "two hundred "; 
    break;
    case 3 : out += "three hundred ";
    break;
    case 4 : out += "four hundred ";
    break;
    case 5 : out += "five hundred ";  
    break;
    case 6 : out += "six hundred ";
    break;
    case 7 : out += "seven hundred ";
    break;
    case 8 : out += "eight hundred ";
    break;
    case 9 : out += "nine hundred ";
    break;
  }
    let tens = parseInt(num / 10)%10;
    let ones = num%10;
    switch (tens) {
    case 0 : break; 
    case 1 : switch (ones) {
    case 0 : out += "ten";
    break; 
    case 1 : out += "eleven";
    break;
    case 2 : out += "twelve"; 
    break;
    case 3 : out += "thirteen";
    break;
    case 4 : out += "fourteen";
    break;
    case 5 : out += "fifteen";  
    break;
    case 6 : out += "sixteen";
    break;
    case 7 : out += "seventeen";
    break;
    case 8 : out += "eighteen";
    break;
    case 9 : out += "nineteen";
    break;
    }
    break;
    case 2 : out += "twenty "; 
    break;
    case 3 : out += "thirty ";
    break;
    case 4 : out += "forty ";
    break;
    case 5 : out += "fifty ";  
    break;
    case 6 : out += "sixty ";
    break;
    case 7 : out += "seventy ";
    break;
    case 8 : out += "eighty ";
    break;
    case 9 : out += "ninety ";
    break;
    }
    if(tens != 1) {
      switch (ones) {
    case 0 : break;
    case 1 : out += "one";
    break;
    case 2 : out += "two"; 
    break;
    case 3 : out += "three";
    break;
    case 4 : out += "four";
    break;
    case 5 : out += "five";  
    break;
    case 6 : out += "six";
    break;
    case 7 : out += "seven";
    break;
    case 8 : out += "eight";
    break;
    case 9 : out += "nine";
    break;
    }
    }
  
  return out;
}

module.exports = function toReadable (number) {
  if(number == 0) {
    return "zero";
  }
  let str1 = number.toString(10);
  if(str1.length < 4) {
    return helpReadable(number);
   } else if(str1.length < 7) {
     let out = helpReadable(number / 1000) + " thousand " + helpReadable(number%1000);
     return out;
   } else {
     let out = helpReadable(number / 1000000) + " million " + helpReadable(number/1000) ; if(helpReadable(number / 1000) != "") {out += ' thousand ' ;}
     out += helpReadable(number%1000);
     return out;
   }
  }
```

Comment: I found an existing solution to this problem here: https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-convert-numbers-to-words-with-javascript-4072535 you can either use this or study this, but if it's just about the challenge, I for one need more information about exactly what help with javascript you need

Comment: This code is probably unusual and my tutor told it's rather suitable for juniors/pre-middles.

Comment: I thought that many people can get interested it, but I'm not sure how to handle it properly. And yes, aside from this issue, everything in the code works correctly. Even my tutor was amazed to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim()` to remove spaces at the start and the end of the string. For example:

```js
console.log(toReadable(1234).trim());
```

Or, if you have to do it inside the function, you can call `trim()` at every `return out` or `return helpReadable(...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I don't actually know where I do need to include this method (and in which quantities)

Comment: Couldn't you write down a part of block that I need to change if you don't really mind?

Comment: I figured it out myself and everything works 100%. You're a hero!!

Answer (score 0):

My way...

```js
console.log( `--${toReadable( 2000000 )}--` )
console.log( `--${toReadable(  200000 )}--` )
console.log( `--${toReadable( 7000011 )}--` )
console.log( `--${toReadable(      23 )}--` )
console.log( `--${toReadable(       0 )}--` )


function toReadable(num)
  {
  const
    mParts = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion' ]
  , arr    = []
  , numArr = []
  , numberStr =
      { '0': 'zero',  '10': 'ten',       '100': 'hundred'
      , '1': 'one',   '11': 'eleven'
      , '2': 'two',   '12': 'twelve',    '20' : 'twenty'
      , '3': 'three', '13': 'thirteen',  '30' : 'thirty'
      , '4': 'four',  '14': 'fourteen',  '40' : 'forty'
      , '5': 'five',  '15': 'fifteen',   '50' : 'fifty'
      , '6': 'six',   '16': 'sixteen',   '60' : 'sixty'
      , '7': 'seven', '17': 'seventeen', '70' : 'seventy'
      , '8': 'eight', '18': 'eighteen',  '80' : 'eighty'
      , '9': 'nine',  '19': 'nineteen',  '90' : 'ninety'
      }
  , digits3 = val =>
    {
    let
      vTen   = val % 100
    , valStr = val.toString(10)  
    , res    = []
      ;
    if (val > 100) res.push( numberStr[valStr[0]], numberStr[100] )
    
    if (val === 0) res.push( numberStr['0'] ) 
    else if (vTen < 20)  
      { if (vTen)  res.push( numberStr[vTen] ) }
    else 
      {
      let n = vTen % 10;
      vTen -= n;
      res.push( numberStr[vTen] )
      if (n>0) res.push( numberStr[n] )
      }
    return res.join(' ')
    }
  let n3d;
  do{
    n3d = num % 1000
    arr.push( n3d )
    num -= n3d
    num /= 1000
    }
    while(num > 0)

  for (let i=arr.length;i--;) 
    {
    if (i>0)
      {
      if (arr[i] > 0) numArr.push(digits3(arr[i]), mParts[i] )
      }
    else if (arr.length===1 || arr[i] > 0 ) 
      numArr.push( digits3(arr[i]) )
    }
  return numArr.join(' ') 
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: Thanks for assistance, but honestly I figured it out myself, scoring 100% so I close this question!

Comment: @alexeyPetrov92  I changed my answer... (isn't it better?)